# Saving loop output in a file only saves last iteration

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm creating a caesar cipher decrypt/encrypt program. My program reads from a .txt file, displays all outputs for the 26 different shifts.

I'm having issues when it comes to saving the output back to a .txt: only the output of the final iteration is the what gets saved to the file. I want to save all 26 iterations instead.

See pictures for examples.

[image: Console Output]

[image: .txt output]

The code that loops and writes to the file:

```
static void decryption()
    {   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        Console.WriteLine ("\n*********************************** Decryption *********************************");
        Console.ResetColor();
        //pulls getPath from varables class
        string path = globalVars.getPath();


    string encrypted_text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);    //String variable that contains the text from a file. To get the text, the method in a class SystemIO is ran to read the text. It expects a parameter, which is a file directory.
    string decoded_text = " ";
    int shift = 0;
    char character = '0';
    encrypted_text = encrypted_text.ToUpper();

    char[] alphabet = new char[26] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

    Console.WriteLine("The encrypted text is \n{0}", encrypted_text);       //Display the encrypted text

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)        //Start a loop which will display 25 different candidates of decipher
    {
        decoded_text = "";
        foreach (char c in encrypted_text)
        {
            character = c;

            if (character == '\'' || character == ' ')
                continue;

            shift = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, character) - i;     //Define a shift which is the index of a character in an alphabet array, take away the itteration of this loop. Store the result in a variable
            if (shift <= 0)
                shift = shift + 26;

            if (shift >= 26)
                shift = shift - 26;


            decoded_text += alphabet[shift];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nShift {0} \n {1}", i + 1, decoded_text);
    }

        string filename;
        string savePath;

        string fileContent = decoded_text;

        Console.WriteLine("What do you want to name your file??");
        filename = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Where would you like to save your file??");
        savePath = Console.ReadLine();

File.WriteAllText(savePath + filename + ".txt", fileContent);
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
        Console.WriteLine(Console.Read());
}
}// ///////END OF DECRYPTION //////////
```

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line `string fileContent = decoded_text;`
You are just assigning fileContent to last decoded text. To fix this put fileContent before loop and then add each decodedText in each step.

Like this:

```
static void decryption()
{   

    // ...
    string fileContent = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
    {
        // ...
        fileContent += "Shift " + (i+1).ToString() + "\r\n" + decoded_text + "\r\n";
    }

    // ...
    File.WriteAllText(savePath + filename + ".txt", fileContent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amir. appreciated!

Comment: And don't use string concatenation to append filenames to directory names: use `Path.Combine(savePath, filename + ".txt")` so you can handle both directories with and without trailing separator character.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice @CodeCaster, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're over-writing the contents of `decoded_text` in your `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)        //Start a loop which will display 25 different candidates of decipher
{
    decoded_text = "";
    foreach (char c in encrypted_text)
    {
        character = c;

        if (character == '\'' || character == ' ')
            continue;

        shift = Array.IndexOf(alphabet, character) - i;     //Define a shift which is the index of a character in an alphabet array, take away the itteration of this loop. Store the result in a variable
        if (shift <= 0)
            shift = shift + 26;

        if (shift >= 26)
            shift = shift - 26;


        decoded_text += alphabet[shift];
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nShift {0} \n {1}", i + 1, decoded_text);
}
```

You assign it an empty string in your `for` loop. Then you add characters to it in your nested `foreach` loop. But then `foreach` ends, `for` loop iterates again and wipes it out with an empty string.

So either remove that entirely, or move it elsewhere, or save the contents to the file before wiping it out-- I don't really understand what you're trying to do, exactly. I mean, I understand a Caesar cipher but your post isn't worded great.

This would be a good time to set some break points, and step through your loops line by line and learn to use the debugging tools.

Comment: If you remove OP's unchanged code and your "go debugging" hint from your answer, you're left with _"The problem is that you're over-writing the contents of decoded_text in your for loop [...] remove that entirely, or move it elsewhere, or save the contents to the file before wiping it out"_. Can you elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: As I said, I didn't entirely understand what exactly he's trying to do so that's why I didn't elaborate more. Amir figured it out already; define `fileContent` before the loop and add `decoded_text` to that before wiping it out. But yea, I guess you're correct; this isn't really a *solution* per se, just saying what he did wrong :/

Comment: _"I didn't entirely understand what exactly he's trying to do"_ - then post a comment, not an answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

Move the line `decoded_text=""` before the for loop. This is what makes the file only contain the last bit of the code.

You also might want to use a StringBuilder in stead of appending a string. This is more efficient.

Comment: This looks like the right answer to me. Maybe you're getting down votes because it could be better explained?

Comment: This answer doesn't really say anything - what does that even mean?

Comment: @Niklas how? What does "put" mean? It is already declared outside the loop.

Comment: Yep, I'm going to explain a bit more next time.

Comment: You can do it now. Down votes are not permanent. Just [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34045179/edit) your post.

Comment: @CodeCaster Just tried to hint to Nemeas that the answer should be improved upon but that he had the basics right. Just down voting this answer is not gonna help him the next time he answers another question.

Comment: @CodeCaster ...and neither did I, but he *did* get two down votes without any explanations. I wanted to help him understand why he got them.